# How to hide this 'Applications' menu in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, menu, arc-menu

I have **Arc Menu** and **Dash to panel** installed. But the following menu still keeps showing (only on main monitor)

[image: Menu Applications]

How can I hide it?

Comment: Where did it come from?

Comment: Man I don't know. I have Ubuntu 20.04.03, Arc Menu and Dash to panel extensions.

https://i.imgur.com/Uf2d7Vg.png

Comment: That doesn't look like Ubuntu Desktop. What version and flavor of Ubuntu are you running?  Perhaps you should disable extensions and customizations one-by-one so you can determine the origin of this feature by process of elimination. You're in a better position than us to troubleshoot this, since you have access to the device and presumably you should know what you installed and customized.

Comment: Correct. I'll clean up what I installed here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is already solved, but let me do it

Open Extensions and disable an in-built extension "Applications tab"

P.S: 2nd day on Linux, it's just the best